# Cannot use Html.ActionLink in asp.net mvc spark files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I'm using the spark view engine with my asp.net mvc application.
In my aspx pages, I can succesfully use Html.Actionlink, but when I attempt it in spark files, it doesnt show up in intellisense, and when i try to run it anyway, i get:

Dynamic view compilation failed.
c:\Users\midas\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ChurchMVC\ChurchMVC\Views\Home\Index.spark(73,25): error CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I do have system.web.mvc referenced, and I have added  in _global.spark.
None of that helps. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Copied from Rei Roldán's answer in [Spark discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/spark-dev/browse_thread/thread/5276b265a3880aeb))

This is where the helpers live.

```
<use namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to get this error even with correct Web.config by declaring ActionLink with wrong argument types.

Example:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(1, "bar") %>
```

Error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Approval.WebSite.ViewsModels.HomeIndexPage>' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

While this works:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("foo", "bar") %>
```

So check your markup as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Html.ActionLink in master layout. The reason was automatic Html encoding. Fixed by setting `<pages automaticEncoding="false">` in web.config or by using  !{Html.ActionLink(...)} instead of ${Html.ActionLink(...)}

Comment: Oops! Sorry, mixed two articles - not "the same problem", a different one.