# Mono 3.2.1 MVC 4 (XSP) System.Web.Mvc assembly trouble

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, xsp

I was trying to deploy .NET 4.5 MVC4 project to the Mono 3.2 XSP and got exception. 

**Software:**

Ubuntu Linux 13.04

Mono 3.2.1 compiled from sources

XSP4 3.0.11 compiled from sources

**Exception text:**

```
CS1701: Warning as Error: Assuming assembly reference `System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches assembly `System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. You may need to supply runtime policy
```

**Stack trace:**

```
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath,     System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.AppResourcesAssemblyBuilder.BuildDefaultAssembly (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 files, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit unit) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.AppResourcesAssemblyBuilder.Build (System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit unit) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.AppResourcesCompiler.CompileGlobal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.AppResourcesCompiler.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.InitType (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Anybody solved it? How to get rid of it?

Comment: Hey, have you checked the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805779/using-asp-net-mvc-2-features-with-the-spark-view-engine

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the only way of getting an MVC3 project working on Mono was by copying some of the Microsoft assemblies to the Mono project, such as (if using Razor):

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Razor
- System.Web.Helpers
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor

Being you're using MVC4 it'll probably be something along the same lines - it's what the exception seems to be hinting (its seeing version 1 and expecting 4). Chances are you'll need different or additional assemblies to these.
Have a look [here](http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p1319/run-asp-net-mvc4-on-mono-monodevelop-on-mac-the-c-template-project), you might find some additional help.

Also, .NET 4.5 is still not fully supported on Mono (no async on MVC4). Expect to find other problems there.